# Formatting of an unsigned long long causes an integer overflow

Tags: c, mingw, number-formatting, unsigned-long-long-int

The `unsigned long long` type doesn't work as expected for me. Here's my simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned long long a = 2932306814;
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
a = -1362660482
```

The used `gcc` was installed as part of mingw and has version 4.8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not printing the number correctly. `%d` specifier is for an `int`. Use the specifier `%llu` for an `unsigned long long`.

Change to:

```
printf("a = %llu\n", a);
```

Comment: Great, that's it! Since its not the overflow issue but just formatting, I should reset the tags properly.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am allowed to do it in 9 minutes.